# Why does my while(read) loop with pipes never end?

Tags: c, string, while-loop, pipe, fgets

```
// Some initialization

// Child process
// stdin is redirected to fd[0]
while (fgets(someCharArray, sizeof(someCharArray), stdin) {
    printf("%s\n", someCharArray);
}

// Parent process
char greeting[50] = "hello\n\0";
write(fd[1], greeting, sizeof(greeting));
close(fd[1]);
```

I'm really baffled by these pipes. `fgets` should read up to and including the newline. It reads, and successfully prints "hello". However, the process doesn't end. I've closed the write end of the pipe of the parent. So it should return 0 or `EOF`, and the while loop should exit.

I've tried different combinations of "hello" with and without the newline character and null-terminator. I really don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Do you also `close` fd[1] in the child process?

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's likely you are not closing all the right fds. So we need to see the complete code.

Comment: @jdarthenay I'm unsure about this. The child process has actually executed another source file. So it has no `fd`. I have tried to `close` `stdout` before the while loop, but that wouldn't make sense. Does this mean I need to pass the `fd` from the main program into the child?

Comment: @jdarthenay OH. Even though I redirect `stdout` of the child to `fd[1]`, I did not know I still needed to close that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have `fd[0]` reach `EOF` you need to have closed `fd[1]` in all the processes who know them.
In your case you should close `fd[1]` in the child process right after the `fork()`

```
if (fork() == 0)
{
    close(fd[1]);
    // ...
    // instructions for child process
    exit 0;
}
```